# Getting rid of strongarm in features export

Tags: features, strongarm

I exported a feature and it came wiht a bunch of strongarm configureation that I didn't want. I was able to delete most of it, but I wasn't sure about this part:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ctools_plugin_api().
 */
function mymodule_ctools_plugin_api() {
  list($module, $api) = func_get_args();
  if ($module == "strongarm" && $api == "strongarm") {
    return array("version" => "1");
  }
}
```

Can I get rid of it altogether, or should I just have it return the version, for ctools?

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is yes you can delete it since you don't have any strongarm stored in this feature.

usually features add 3 pieces of code to any exported type:

1. the configuration it self in a file feature_name.features.config_group.inc or feature_name.config_group.inc
2. the include part in features feature_name.features.inc
3. what are the content of the export in feature_name.info

you can delete those manually and the feature will act as if they where never there, though removing a complete set of config group (e.g: remove all strongarm config) form the features UI will usually leave you with config file .config_group.inc (1), and rarely with include settings in .features.inc, which you can delete them manually.